# Is there a connection between color temperature concept and Hershel's color temperature experiment through which he discovered infrared?

Tags: visible-light, temperature

I just watched a Cosmos episode about Hershel's experiment, of which i think i was not aware. According to it, red light temperature is higher than blue (measured in celsius). As far as I know, however, color temperature is measured in kelvins, and blue has higher temperature than red. Are these two separate concepts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are mixing up two different things.

To take your second point first: when light is emitted from a [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body) the spectrum of the the light is related to the temperature of the black body by [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law). Basically the hotter the black body the bluer the light. So a very hot emitter produces light with most of its power at the blue end of the spectrum, and a lower temperature emitter produces light with most of its power at the red end of the spectrum.

And this brings us to your first point about Hershel's experiment. Hershel used sunlight, which has a black body temperature of around 5700K and has its peak power around yellow wavelengths. So all else being equal he would have measured the highest temperature in the yellow part of the spectrum.

However the prism Hershel used did not spread out the light evenly. His prism spread out the yellow part of the spectrum more than the red part, and it spread out the blue end of the spectrum even more. The result was that in his spectrum the peak intensity was in the red/infra-red region. That's why he recorded the highest temperatures in the red/infra-red.